# What happened with the file?

Tags: files-and-directories

What happened with this file?

```
infile = "\\test data.txt";  

outstr = OpenWrite[infile];
instr = OpenRead[infile];
Read[instr, Record];
Close[instr];
```

All content of "test data.txt" was lost.

Comment: You should have used `OpenAppend`.

Answer (score 12):

[From the help](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html)

> `OpenWrite["file"] open an output stream to a file, wiping out the previous contents of the file`

... it's gone, you deleted it :